# Object reference not set to an instance of an object unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having that error when I am trying to execute the following code.All it should do is set the panel with the tag "Player1" to false and the one with "Player2" to true.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Events : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Variables.Player1Turn == false)
        {
         GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1").SetActive(false);
         GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player2").SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thing is, "Events" and "Variables" are components of  empty objects that do not go away.

Here is what "Variables" contains:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Variables : MonoBehaviour {

    static public string Player1Choice=null;
    static public bool Player1Turn=true;
    static public string Player2Choice=null;
    static public bool Player2Turn=true;
}
```

Player1Turn goes false when a button on the panel tagged with "Player 1" is pressed.

Note: I do know that the SystemNullReference Exception is thrown at

```
 GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player2").SetActive(true);
```

I, however, cannot find a way around it.

What should I do to make the first panel dissapear and the second one appear without encountering this error?

Comment: I edited the original post, I could not find help within the specified link.

Comment: More than likely, `FindGameObjectWithTag` is returning _null_ on which you then attempt to call `SetActive` resulting in the exception.